# Recommendations for Simplifying MySQL Table with Many Search Criteria Columns

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL table `search_table` that we use to search records based on multiple unsigned integer criteria (val1, val2, val3, etc). The table has a `cid` column used for joining with another table.

```
CREATE TABLE search_table (
  cid int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  val1 int unsigned default 0,
  val2 int unsigned default 0,
  ...
  KEY (val1),
  KEY (val2),
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The current approach defines each criteria column (val1, val2, etc) separately with its own index. As the number of criteria has grown to 18 and will reach ~30 soon, managing all these columns has become messy.

I am looking for an idea on what would be a better database design? We're open redesign entire table to simplify the table structure for manageability.

Thank you!

Comment: Whatever all these `val` columns mean, it would be better to use a normalized database design

Comment: they all are independent values so can't be normalized. For example, one value is gender, another is DoB and so on. And we can't keep on creating joins on such large number of conditions. And hence they need to be in a single table

Comment: perhaps an eav model https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: Do you set all or at least most of these values for all rows in the table?

Comment: at least 8-10 basic values are set for all users. Rest are optional.

Comment: eav is a good suggestion, thanks P.salmon.